# How to suppress "not all code paths return a value" error message in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When I have a method in Visual Studio (2019) that's not returning all code paths, as expected I get the error message that states: "not all code paths return a value".

My blood pressure increases every time the squiggly appears on the method name.
Is it possible to suppress this error so the squigglies go away?

If I screw up and forget, I just want the compiler to whine in the error console after the fact.
I use ReSharper as well, haven't been able to find a setting in there regarding it so far.

Comment: You could type `return null` on the line before the end of the function. (Adjust according to language.)

Comment: i know...but the squiggly will still be there initially which will have already raised my blood pressure

Comment: You could use `#Disable Warning BC42353` before the function, and `#Enable Warning BC42353` after it, although the compiler won't complain either.

Comment: Alternatively, you can go "Project" menu -> "yourProject Properties..." -> "Code Analysis" tab -> "Configure" button, find `BC42353` and change it. Ctrl-S to save so VS sees the change. Remember to re-enable it, it's possible that you could do some sort of pre-build script for that, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: I'm working on a dotnet core 3 app. unfortunately the code analysis tab has been deprecated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My resolution was switching to JetBrains Rider.
Not only does it not annoy you with squiggles, you can configure the IDE to automatically generate the default for the return type (among other options as well).

Side note, I was very surprised at how functional Rider is.
Most importantly, it's significantly faster and more stable than Visual Studio.
Well worth the cost.